# RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout won't wrap content correctly

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to make a simple clock/stopwatch app. In my overall vertical linear layout, I have a relative layout followed by a button. The relative layout has several imageviews stacked on each other in order to produce the clock.

I noticed, however, that the relative layout, as well as the imageviews themselves, take up way too much space in the linear layout. The clock pieces are SQUARE, so why is Eclipse insisting that it is a long vertical rectangle? My button at the bottom doesn't even show if I don't use weights. (But strangely enough, it shows if it is above the relative layout.)

I've tried everything I could: Set the height of items in relative layout to wrap_content, as well as the relative layout itself. I tried using weights, by giving the relativelayout a weight of 0 and the button 1, and then setting their layout_heights respectively to 0dp as needed. Still no go. There is a lot of room left for other things, and I'd like for the clock's parent layout to wrap itself around just the content.

What is going on here? Please see attached image for details. Code is attached below.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tiling_rules"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/clock" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/hour" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/min" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sec" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bell" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Test" />
```

[image: How it looks vertically]
[image: How it looks horizontally]
[image: How I want the layout to wrap itself.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that all I needed was to add:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to every ImageView! Now the clock pieces' bounds are "wrapped" around the content, even though setting wrap_content in its layout didn't work. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a RelativeLayout as your main layout. This way you can make the button show at the bottom of the screen. Then if you need, use a separate layout for the clock pieces within the main layout

Kinda like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/clock" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/hour" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/min" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sec" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bell" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: Taking your advice, I did just that. The button now shows at the bottom, BUT the clock is still taking up too much space. (Lots of empty space left surrounding it).

Comment: If it isn't inconvenient for you, you could specify the size of height and width in the xml. I would use dp so it will auto scale depending on screen density